# Can the integral of a function be larger than function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Are there any non zero(i.e not $f \equiv0  $) and non-negative continuous function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$, which satisfies $\int_0^x{f(t)}dt \geq f(x)~ \forall x$ in $[0,1]$?

Comment: $f(t) = -c$ where $c > 0$ .

Comment: Note that this does *not* rule out Guru's answer - maybe you want to say *non-constant* instead?

Comment: sorry f(x) should be non negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set it is bounded and achieves both its minimum and maximum, $m=f(x_0)$ and $M=f(x_1)$. Since $f$ is non-constant these are distinct. Pick any $c\in(m,M)$. Without loss of generality assume $x_0<x_1$ By continuity there is some interval $(a,b)\in[0,1]$ containing $x_0$ on which $f<c$. Thus

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt \le \int_a^b cdt = c(b-a) < M(b-a)$$

Note the strict inequality.  Then

$$\int_0^{x_1} f(t)dt$$

$$=\int_0^a f(t)dt + \int_a^b f(t)dt + \int_b^{x_1} f(t)dt$$

$$\le M(a-0) + \int_a^b f(t)dt + M(x_1-b)$$

$$< M(a-0) + M(b-a) + M(x_1-b)$$

$$= Mx_1\le M=f(x_1)$$

Thus

$$\int_0^{x_1} f(t)dt < f(x_1)$$

Comment: I got it, but after looking your answer I got that just have to apply mean value theorem on any smaller sub interval [0,b] It will be an two line argument $\int^{x_1}_0{f(x)}dx=f(c)(x_1-0)\geq{f(x_1)}$  the equality case only f is 0

Answer (score 18):

Use the integrating factor $e^{-x}$ to find
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\int_0^xf(s)ds\right)\le 0
$$
so that after integration
$$
e^{-x}\int_0^xf(s)ds-e^0·0\le 0
$$
and thus
$$
f(x)\le\int_0^xf(s)ds\le 0
$$

As $f$ is supposed to be non-negative, the only solution is the zero function.

---

See also [Grönwall lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality).

Comment: I'm sure I'm being obtuse, but -- where does your first inequality come from?

Comment: @ruakh: The derivative is just $e^{-x}(f(x) - \int^x_0 f)$, which is non-negative everywhere by hypothesis.

Comment: @anomaly: Oh, I see now -- thanks!